# How to get a number that has been declared in an array more than once in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble getting a number that has been declared in a array more than once in php.

Here's my array

```
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 24 [2] => 25 )
```

As you can see `24` has been declared more than once in this array so I want my code to give me back `24`.

Here's another array

```
Array ( [0] => 22 [1] => 22 [2] => 25 [3] => 25 [4] => 25 )
```

As you can see `25` has been declared more than once in this array so I want my code to give me back `25`

Comment: What have you tried so far? You only show the array declaration and no code. You could use a `foreach` loop transversing the array and determining which elements have dupes.

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution that comes to mind is iterating over a unique set of values and unsetting they key. Fortunately, [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) will keep your keys, i.e.

```
$array = [24, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 24];
var_dump(array_unique($array));
```

will yield the following:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  int(24)
  [2]=>
  int(25)
  [3]=>
  int(26)
  [4]=>
  int(27)
  [5]=>
  int(28)
}
```

So you just iterate over this array and unset the original values by key:

```
foreach (array_unique($array) as $key=>$value)
{
    unset($array[$key]);
}

var_dump($array);
```

This will produce the following:

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  int(24)
  [6]=>
  int(24)
}
```

If you need `24` only once, just run `array_unique` over result `$array` again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do use some core functions to achieve this,

```
$a = [0 => 24, 1 => 24, 2 => 25];
$temp = array_count_values($a);

natsort($temp);
pr(array_search(array_values(array_reverse($temp, true))[0], $temp));
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e52bb66d57a13abd65695552a958407cc5b31532)

**Edit**

To get all key value pairs which appeared once,

```
$result = array_keys($temp,1);
print_r($result);
```

You can check output of it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f3c0bed345a0334bef7658f2bec62b92a2b464c6).

[array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array

**Syntax:**

```
array_keys ( array $array , mixed $search_value [, bool $strict = FALSE ] ) : array
```

> Note: If a search_value is specified, then only the keys for that
>   value are returned. Otherwise, all the keys from the array are
>   returned.

Comment: Hello this code did work but I just want to know is there anyway I can refactor this to work with checking if a number has been declared only once in an array? 

Comment: @fuzzybuddy aBSOlutely! `print_r($temp)` to check for the elements which appeared only once. But is your question "I want to fetch those values which appreared only once in an array?"